# Exoplayer using too much cpu in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer

Ok so I started working with google's ExoPlayer and created a custom view that I can initiate and call `myView.setUp(VideoUri)` to start playing a video with exoPlayer, now everything works smoothly when the view is in an activity, user cpu usage for the app is between 9-11% then in another activity I have a recyclerview and only one custom view that I attach and detach to a container in the recyclerview's items knowing that the items are sized so only one item is completely visible at a time. Once the customview is attached to an item in the recyclerview cpu usage jumps to nearly 30-35% which after a few minutes causes the phone to heat up. the custom view's performance is fine since it performs well when not in a list now I would like to know what could be causing this jump in CPU usage once it is in a list ? Does exoplayer behave differently when placed in a list?

Comment: Whil eonly one item is visible it does not mean RV is not loading more than one. Try calling RecyclerView#setItemViewCacheSize(0);

Comment: @X3Btel yes I am aware of that, I said only one item is "Completely" visible, you can see the top and bottom of the other items but their containers are empty since once the user scrolls, the custom view with the player is detached from the last completly visible item and attached to the new one.